# Can't change send data through rails ajax event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

From this [wiki](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax), event `ajax:beforeSend` has extra two arguments [xhr, settings], but actually I log them to show undefined.

HTML code:

```
<%=link_to 'Save', @article, remote: true, method: :put, id: 'save' %>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$('#save').on('ajax:beforeSend', function (event, xhr, settings) {
  console.log(xhr) // => undefined
  console.log(settings) // => undefined
}
```

Rails version: 5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
`$('#save').on(` 
to 
`$('#save').bind(`

Comment: I know I am using rails-ujs not jquery-ujs, rails-ujs doesn't show any extra arguments in event callback such as xhr, settings. But I don't know why they behave so different, this is rails [wiki](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#dealing-with-ajax-events) said.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 5.1, `rails-ujs` replaces `jquery-ujs` and its API is slightly different. Instead sending `xhr` and `settings` as additional parameters, they can be found in `event.detail` as first and second elements of an array.

Comment: I agree, but rails developer don't update the document.